# How to write interval in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with lexicographic order

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to express an interval with the lexicographic order on $\mathbb{R}^2$, but I'm a little confused about the notation. Specifically, I'd like to express the set of all values of $x$ greater than $0$ and all values of $x$ less than $2$, with all values of $y$ included between these two $x$ values. So it would look like a strip in the plane from $0$ to $2$ with dotted lines along $x=0$ and $x=2$. Would this be $(0\times \{y\},2\times \{y\})$? Or am I overcomplicating things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write it as $A = ((0, \infty), (2, -\infty))$. This means that $(x, y) \in A$ if and only if $x > 0$, or if $x = 0$ and $y > \infty$, and $x < 2$, or if $x = 2$ and $y < -\infty$. Since both of the latter conditions are impossible, it means that $(x, y) \in A$ if and only if $0 < x < 2$.

Alternatively, I would write it as $A = (0, 2) \times \mathbb{R}$. That is, $(x, y) \in A$ if and only if $0 < x < 2$. I like this one slightly less, as it doesn't refer to the fact that we're using the Lexographic order, but for general use, I prefer this one.

Answer (score 2):

The Cartesian product ($\times$) is an operation on two sets. Since 0 is not a set, $0 \times \{y\}$ does not make sense.

I think this is the notation you're looking for:
$$(0, 2) \times \mathbb{R}$$

Alternatively you could write:
$$\{(x,y)\ |\ 0<x<2, y \in \mathbb{R}\}$$